# Babel es2015 presets doesn't translate Map and Set to es5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phantomjs, karma-runner, babeljs

I'm using gulp-babel to translate my es6 code to es5

```
gulp.task('build_all_debug', ['config', 'compile'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src(['public/js/config.js', 'public/js/*.js', 'public/compiled/*.js'])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'));
    return stream;
});
```

While it mostly works fine, it doesn't actually translate Map and Set. My result js code still includes them, and when I run unit test with karma/mocha/phantomJs, I got the following error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) notes.controller "before each" hook: workFn for "loads notes from the service" FAILED
    Can't find variable: Map
    activate@public/dist/app.js:2402:39
```

Is there any way to force babel to translate Map and Set to object and array in es5?

Comment: If you're using ES6 via Babel, you should really not be concatenating your files together. You're going to run into trouble if you do that rather than using a module bundler.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, can you please suggest what module bundler is the 'usual' choice for babel? I'm feeling like in a rabbit hole now, the only reason I use babel is because I can't compile typescript directly to es5 due to the same Map/Set issue, for compatibility I have to use babel, it was quite easy by adding a babel pipe, but now it looks like I need to change the whole building process?

Comment: A relatively normal workflow these days would be a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include [`babel-polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) in your code.

You have to install it with npm:

```
npm install babel-polyfill
```

and then, if you're using ES6 modules:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

or:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
```

If you want to run your code in browser, you can load it from cdnjs:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.16.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately since the OP uses gulp-concat, it has no module system and thus no easy way to do this :(

Comment: @loganfsmyth So it's not possible to use any external modules with `gulp-concat`?

Comment: `babel-polyfill` is CommonJS, so I guess you'd have to run browserify on it and then concat that onto your bundle?

Comment: @loganfsmyth It's also [available on cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-polyfill), so it can be included using a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Ah true enough.

Comment: @Gothdo, is CDN the only way to use babel-polyfill without a module? I'm using bower, there is a babel-polyfill package on bower, am I right I can install and use that one? the CDN does resolve the problem, but it's not nice to rely on an external links for my unit test

Comment: @swang I don't know bower, but if there's a babel-polyfill bower package, you probably can use it. Just make sure that it gets included before your code.

Comment: Had similar issue with mocha - `Array.flatten` didn't work in specs. Solved by `mocha ... --require babel-polyfill`

Answer (score 5):

Babel can't "translate" `Map` and `Set`, because they aren't language features (although they are described in the ES spec). They're classes that exist in the global scope.

You should use a polyfill that defines the ES6 collections, so you can keep using them in browsers that don't provide support. I'm not sure what library Babel uses, but [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) should cover all the major parts.

You won't need to change your code any to use the polyfill, it just defines `Map` (and friends) for normal use later.

Comment: am I right es6-shim is a non-browser non-babel-specific library that can be used by browser, node and babel? should i prefer babel-polyfill in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Babel does not transpile `Map` and `Set` to ES5.

Instead, use their [polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/):

> In order to support Maps, Sets, WeakMaps, and WeakSets in all environments you must include the Babel polyfill.

[Source](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/)